# Cakephp ajax Autocomplete not working

Tags: cakephp, autocomplete

I am using ajax autocomplete in my application, but it is not giving the output. 
Ajax request to the desired function goes but it is not giving back any response, it is blank.

I am also using jquery but it is used for other effects. i added jquery no conflict to avoid the prototype & jquery conflicts.

I have tried other ajax helper methods like obeserverfield, it is working fine & returning the proper response, but when i use autocomplete it fails

Can anybody help me ..........

Answer (score 0):

Ha..........

Finally i got solution of my problem.....

The problem was with the 'Security' component..

I searched, tried most of the ways & read a lot of post about the autocomplete issue, but no luck.

But while searching on google groups i got one hint & tried that solution & finally it work........

When i removed this component from the list then my auto complete started working properly...

Here is a question.....

Why this happens, is security component restricts the autocomplete actions or its an bug with the cakephp?

Use full link : http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/87bb4bde3d5c6ffe/4faecbb7c20f782a?lnk=gst&q=autocomplete+